# iOS - 500 error occurs when trying to post an image to server

Tags: php, objective-c, ios7

I'm currently working on an upload image function for an iPhone app

the code below is working fine for the localhost

```
- (void) imageUpload:(UIImage *) image{

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString *urlString = @"http://xxxxxxxxxx/uploadtest/upload.php";

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

//start uploading
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
//get return string
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",returnString);  
}
```

however, when I try this code for my server, it will return me a 500 internal server error...
after debugging, I fund that, the bug will not appears when I remove `@"multipart/form-data;"` from http header of the request

```
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
```

But I cannot get any file data from my php file without `"multipart/form-data"`

I wonder if there is any setting in the server that disable the file uploading limitation or my code's problem...
Please help me if anyone have the solution for this
thanks~

Comment: then check your php file. there is some errors on php script

Comment: the code works fine for localhost~ it can upload image successfully~ so the php file is OK there~

Comment: 500 error code is an internal server error so this means one of two things. (1) The server is breaking when receiving the HTTP request and is a problem with the server. or (2) the server is receiving the HTTP request and is breaking because it is formatted incorrectly